# Inviting test users facebook SDK?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-test-users

I have integrated my game with facebook in unity. My sharing and leaderboards work properly. The problem is with invites(FB.AppRequest). I am able to send them but they are never received by others. I know fb doesnt allow publish_actions without approval and i have created the test users but am still unable to invite them. 
How can i invite test user to play the game using facebook sdk since they are already friends with each other and using the app?

Comment: Have you tried the sample app bundled with the latest SDK? does it work for you? if so, this should be a good start for you to debug why a similar feature is not working in your game

Comment: Invites from mobile apps (IOS/Android) are only displayed on FB mobile app. For some reason, they are not visible on desktop even if you are looking at all platforms.